# Page scrolled to the bottom when opened

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I have a page setup with a 100% height "content-wrapper" and a max-width so it shows side-gutters (and the body background) when opened on vertical displays (low width). This div is causing the page to open scrolled completly to the bottom, instead of at the top like a regular page should.

Problem occurs on Chrome 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit), I haven't tested other browsers.

CSS:

```
html {
    /*background: url(img/bg.jpg) repeat center center fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;*/
}

body {
    /*background-color: transparent !important;*/
    background: linear-gradient(42deg, #0a193b, #072760);
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.no-padding {
    padding:0 !important;
}

.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#container-content {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;

    max-width: 60em;
    width:1366px;
    height:100%;
    /*padding:0 20px 0 20px;*/
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:2rem;

    background-color: #FEFEFE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em #000;
}

#header {
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:18px;
}

.navigation {
    text-align:right;
    padding:10px 30px 0 0;
}

#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#1a1d25;
    text-align:center;
}

#video-banner {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    max-height:500px;
    margin-top:-14px;
}

#whoami {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:95%;
    padding:20px;
    background:#ececec;
}

#mypic {
    max-width:200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container-content">
        <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
                        LOGO
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 navigation">
                        Início Sobre Portfolio Contactos
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="banner">
                <video id="video-banner" autoplay loop>
                  <source src="timelapse.webm" type="video/webm">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>

            <div id="whoami">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <img class="img-circle" id="mypic" src="img/eu_cut.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9" style="background-color:pink;">
                        Lorem ipsum dolore madre mia conho putana milho
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="works">
                portfolio
                <button value="click"></button>
            </div>

            <div class="window">
                <div class="window-header">
                    <div class="action-buttons"></div>
                    <select class="language">
                        <option value="javascript" selected>JavaScript</option>
                        <option value="markup">HTML</option>
                        <option value="php">PHP</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="window-body">
                    <textarea class="code-input">// Switch the language and put some code on me :)           ↑↑↑↑↑↑
// This is a 'Hello World' example.

function greetings(name){
    name = name || "stranger";
    return "Hello, " + name + "!";
}

window.onLoad = alert(greetings());</textarea>
                    <pre class="code-output">
                        <code class="language-javascript">

                        </code>
                    </pre>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                mini-img-logo-here?
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/code-editor.js"></script>
</body>
```

**You can see the full page [here (link)](http://tiagomartins.eu/teste/).**

There are:

- No tags left unclosed
- No autofocus fields

And changing the 'content-wrapper' div display property maked the page open at top, but completly breaks it, so I think that the problem lies with this div.

How can i fix this and make the page open at the top like a regular one without the JavaScript ScrollTop solution?

Comment: provide fiddle or link please

Comment: @AlaaMh question updated with a link.

Comment: Cannot reproduce

Comment: @TristanWiley clicking the link i posted, the page opens at the top?

Comment: Correct, nothing weird happens.